# register_taxonomy() take much queries

Tags: php, functions, taxonomy, query

Sorry for my poor English, I'm russian.

I have a problem by adding a lot of taxonomies.
When I added about 80 taxonomies, I get the following results(without caching):
before: 44 queries 0.352 seconds
after: 206 queries 0.703 seconds
What's wrong? I calculate that 1 registered taxonomy take 2 server query..

Please, help me..

Comment: There is nothing `wrong` per se, this is how it works. The real question is, why on earth would you be adding 80 taxonomies? :/